# JFileChooser Hanging After Dialog Closes

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, io

I want to start by saying that I'm new to swing. So all that I am trying to do if use a JFileChooser to select a directory. I can open, navigate and select a directory. The problem comes when I press any button that closes the dialog. When I do that then my application freezes. When ever it freezes just the panel that the dialog box is returning to turns white. When I step with the debugger the hang happens immediately aftet the dialog closes and the if statement is not reached. Also I am doing this inside of an Eclipse plugin if that makes a different. In particular it is hosted inside of a View. Code below:

```
public class TexturePacker extends ViewPart {
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
        frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
        frame.add(new TexturePackerPanel(frame));
    }
}

public class TexturePackerPanel extends JPanel {
    //This is called from initialize(), which is called in the constructor
    private void initializeConfigPanel() {
        JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextBoxk outputDirectory = new JTextField();
        configPanel.add(inputDirectory);
        JButton fileButton = new JButton("Folder");
        fileButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser(outputDirectory.getText());
                file.setDialogTitle("Select Output Directory");
                file.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
                file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                int returnVal = file.showDialog(frame, "Choose");
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    outputDirectory.setText(file.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
            //Other blank MouseListener methods//       
        });
        configPanel.add(fileButton);
    }
}
```

System Info:
Windows 8 64bit
Java 7
Eclipse 4.2 SR1 EE Edition

I'm pretty sure that the problem is caused by Swing not playing nice inside of eclipse. I have successfully gotten it working using SWT Directory Dialog. So I am going to just convert the whole JPanel to SWT. Thanks everyone's help, I now know a lot more about how Swing works.

Comment: Are you certain you're executing this code within [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)?

Comment: @user592704 I added the JTextBox initialization in.

Answer (score 0):

For this you really should be using an ActionListener instead of a MouseListener.

Aside from that I think this is a threading issue. You should read the documents on concurrency in [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Surround the `JFileChooser` part with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    \\Your JFileChooser bit
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I've run the following slightly edited code but can't reproduce your problem

```
public static void main(final String[] args){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();
            final JButton fileButton = new JButton("Folder");
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(configPanel);
            //      JButton outputDirectory = new JButton("XX");
            fileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0) {
                    final JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
                    file.setDialogTitle("Select Output Directory");
                    file.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
                    file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

                    final int returnVal = file.showDialog(frame, "Choose");
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        // outputDirectory.setText(file.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                        System.out.println(returnVal);
                    }

                }
            });
            configPanel.add(fileButton);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is ActionListener more favorable that MouseListener, and I tried the above and it didn't help. Also this method, SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), says that my code is in the Event Dispatch Thread

Comment: The MouseEvent contains information that from looking at your code you don't need such as the position of the mouse click. Your code is more verbose with all the methods in MouseListener that you don't need. I can't reproduce your issue exactly as your code is not a SSCCE as @Andrew Thopmson said above

Comment: Well I'm not sure how much more I can show, there isn't that much more. I am running this inside of a view, in an eclipse plugin that I am creating. So I suspect that is what is causing the problem.